# GUI to executable, doesn't working when opening .exe file

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I created a GUI.

It is working fine.
This is the code.

```
# Run A TKinter Application Script

#Create Window
window=Tk()
window["bg"] = "gray"
window.title('SPS Automation App')
window.geometry('500x250')


def browse_files():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    filename = '\"' + filename + '\"'
    print(filename)
    label2 = Label(window)
    if len(str(filename)) > 3:  
        label2['text'] = filename
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You didn\'t upload any file yet.'

    label2.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    

def run():
    os.system('python Test6.py ' + filename)
    #os.system('python Old_Test.py')
    #subprocess.call(['python','Test6.py', filename])
    #print('python Test6.py ' + filename)
    label3 = Label(window)
    label3['text'] = 'Success!'
    
    
#def run2():
 #   os.system('python concatenateOBM.py)


Button1 = Button(window, text='Upload SPS', fg='black', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=browse_files)
Button1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

Button2 = Button(window, text='Create OBM', fg='green', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=run)
Button2.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

#Button3 = Button(window, text='Convert multiple OBMs to 1 OBM', fg='green', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=run2)
#Button3.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

But then I create a executable by running:
pyinstaller GUI.py --noconsole

It creates all folders without error, I then go to dist folder and double click the .exe file, it starts loading, stops and nothing happens.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem lies here `os.system('python Test6.py ' + filename)` are you sure that the file `Test6.py` is in the same directory as the GUI executable?

Comment: I did put in the same directory, but no success. When I started my pc the day after, it showed this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUI_SPS_Automation_Good.py", line 21, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system'                                                                                  Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Hello! Please post all the code so that I could understand better.